# Remove multiple features from the vector by category

Tags: openlayers

`vectorSource.clear()` will remove all features. I want to remove specific features by category:

I am adding the features on the vector. Data comes from json response.

```
data.forEach(device => {
    console.log(device)

    let feature_ = new ol.Feature({
        category: device.fields.category,
        id: device.pk,
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([Number(device.fields.longitude), Number(device.fields.latitude)]).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    })
    feature_.setStyle(iconStyle('/static/applications/images/default.png'))
    feature_.setId(device.id)
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature_)
})
```

Comment: You would need to loop through your ids and call `vectorSource.removeFeature(vectorSource.getFeatureById(id));` for each

Comment: Title says "remove by id", question says "remove by category". Which one?

Comment: It's actually category ID to be correct. Each category has its features. However there is a problem. I set the same (category id) for each feature, and the icons are only displayed once on the map.

Comment: Is it possible to set something that can be used for many features? Like an attribute, then remove all features that have that attribute

Comment: I figured this out: I use `feature_.setId(categoryID+'_'+index)` for the ID. Then to remove it, having the `categoryID` , I loop through each feature and remove it by `vectorSource.removeFeature(vectorSource.getFeatureById(categoryID+'_'+index))`